# POST http://localhost:3000/upload 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, html, amazon-s3

I have an error when I send data from client side (angular.js) to server side (node.js).
I created a form that the user insert data then my controller get the data and sent it to the server to save the data in mongoose and s3(amazon).
I must say that it works fine - I mean I can save all the information I need, I can see it in my DB and I can see the image on s3

but, I get an error : `POST http://localhost:3000/upload 500 (Internal Server Error)`

my html form:

```
<html ng-app="mymed">
 <head>
 <title>insert</title>
 </head>
 <body ng-controller="tryController">
 <main>
 <body>
        <form class="form-group" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="http://localhost:3000/upload">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Title" ng-model="Title" name="Title" required></input>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <br>
            <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" ng-modle="file"></input>
            </div>
          </div>
           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="send" ng-click="createInsert()"></input>
        </form>
.....
<script src="js/appController.js"></script>
```

my controller:

```
mymedical.controller('tryController',['$scope','$http','$cookies', function($scope,$http,$cookies){

        $scope.createInsert = function(){     
                var data = {};    
                data.Title = $scope.Title;
                data.file = $scope.file;      
              $http.post('http://localhost:3000/upload', JSON.stringify(data)).then() //callback
        }
}]);
```

sever side:

```
exports.saveDatatry=function(request, response){

console.log(request.body);

var file = request.files.file;
    var hash = hasher();

    var stream = fs.createReadStream(file.path)
    var mimetype = mime.lookup(file.path);
    console.log(stream);
    var req;

    if (mimetype.localeCompare('image/jpeg')
        || mimetype.localeCompare('image/pjpeg')
        || mimetype.localeCompare('image/png')
        || mimetype.localeCompare('image/gif')) {

        req = client.putStream(stream, hash+'.png',
            {
                'Content-Type': mimetype,
                'Cache-Control': 'max-age=604800',
                'x-amz-acl': 'public-read',
                'Content-Length': file.size
            },
            function(err, result) {
             var savePerTry = new personal({
                  Title: request.body.Title,
                  file: req.url
              });
              savePerTry.save(function(error, result) {
                if (error) {
                  console.error(error);
                } else {
                  console.log("saved!");
                  response.redirect('http://localhost:8080/tryinsert.html');
                };
              })
          });
       } else {
            console.log(err);
        }

}
```

What I need to do?
Thanks,

Comment: have you got the node logs?  500 is a generic error

Comment: _“What I need to do?”_ – first of all, obviously and of course: Check the error logs.

Comment: that is all the errors i get - on the node side it's working fine

Comment: _“on the node side it's working fine”_ – no it is not, otherwise node would not tell you there was an internal _server_ error.

Comment: ok how can I check the log error in node side?@CBroe

Comment: Can you please post the code of your `upload` endpoint?

Comment: I upload look @DavidR

Comment: Edit the title of the question. Is a very poor subject.

Comment: In your controller, while making your `$http.post` call, do you have the success and error call back in your `then` promise?. By looking at your code, I don't see anything as such

Answer (score 4):

Here's your problem:

```
        function(err, result) {
          var savePerTry = new personal({
              Title: request.body.Title,
              file: req.url
          });
```

Every time you write something like:

```
        function(err, result) {
```

then the very next line should be:

```
            if (err) {
              // ...
            }
```

When you don't handle the errors you will get 500 internal server errors and you will not know what's wrong.

Always handle errors.

Comment: I get this error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined